# Odd Issue (Possible Expected Feature) Delete Contact then Account Contact NOT undeleted or undeleteable

Tags: account, contact, recycle-bin, undelete

Ok, so ran into this issue and maybe it is a "feature" but have not ran into it before......

1. Delete a contact
2. Contact shows up in recycle bin
3. Delete Account
4. Account is in recycle bin but contact is NOT in recycle bin
5. Recover Account, contact is NOT undeleted and is still not in recycle bin so cannot be undeleted

Alternate

1. Delete Account
2. Account is in recycle bin
3. Contact is NOT in recycle bin but is deleted
4. Undelete Account
5. Contact IS undeleted

So, why is it that deleting the contact first then the account causes the contact to not be undeleted. If the relationship is seen by the recycle bon thus preventing the contact from being displayed should it not be undeleted with the account??

The issue here is with a 1-1 contact relationship in an OEM model where the subscriber deletes the contact and then the triggers remove the account there is no way to easily get the contact and all its children back without data loader work.

Is this expected behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like that is by design according to [this](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000123575&language=en_US) help article:

> **Resolution**
>   When a record is deleted it is placed into the Recycle Bin.
>   It is considered to be soft deleted and can be restored without issue
>   through the user interface.
>
> However, if the record that is deleted is a child record of any master
>   detail relationship, standard or custom, and the parent record is
>   subsequently deleted, the child record is moved into a hard deleted
>   state and cannot be restored.  Once hard deleted, you will no longer
>   be able to locate the record through the user interface but for a
>   time, you can still see the record through the API using a variety of
>   tools such as the Data Loader or Apex Explorer.
>
> At this time the only option to restore the child record in this
>   situation, or any record that is hard deleted, is to re-import the
>   information back into Salesforce.   This would apply to the following
>   and more standard relationships as well as any custom master-detail
>   relationships: